# Is there any way to customize the autocomplete popup menu vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Kindly upvote the feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113463

I am creating an extension and I need to customize the suggestionsMenu. I want to add numbers at the end of the suggestions.
[image]

I am not asking for complete solution. I am only asking for start up for just to edit the autocomplete menu and add some custom text at end of it. I have searched alot but not found a way to edit the auto complete menu.

**Edit:** Searching for this I found out that it maybe linked `vscode.CompletionItemProvider`

**Edit:** It don't want numbers specifically at end of line. They could be in start of the complete item.

**Note:** I have opened an issue on github https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113463

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, even with a completion provider, because the API only works with strings. The presentation is entirely done by Monaco. Maybe you can use some CSS tricks, but that's not a reliable solution.

Comment: @MikeLischke I am very new to this. Is there any way we could list of all suggestions being shown and then we could overwrite those.

Comment: @MikeLischke I don't need a very reliable solution. I just want to make simple shift tab like it vim. If you have any way please share it in answer.

Comment: Could you share your existing code?

Comment: i am new to extension development, did found some guide links, see if they helps : 
trigger method for getting a list Completion Items : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider

Completion Item Definition : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem 
You can add your custom values into : additionalTextEdits, or to details property

Comment: The (additional)TextEdit(s) are the values that are applied in the editor when selecting the completion item. They have nothing to do with the displayed item list.

Comment: So the "suggestions-widget" is highly customizable, just not by an extension. Each user is able to completley customize it to their own liking. Thats why they don't allow extensions to be written for it, because then each extension would have to add support for the level of cusomization thats offered now, which would not happen.

Comment: The suggestion widget will likely never be fully-accessable by the VSCode API, there are some ideas floating around though that would allow extension developers to write any sort of window like extension they want (sort of) its a sandbox-electron implementation, and they plan on releasing it in the near future. How small the windows will be, and if they can be activated by what a person types is still to be decided, but its an exciting feature that would exalt VSCode beyond all other development environments in the same category as it, if its not already the best.